# The inverse Fourier transform of $\widehat{\varphi}(\xi)e^{-4\pi^2 i|\xi|^2 t}$

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

I need help to compute the following integral

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\widehat{\varphi}(\xi)e^{-4\pi^2 i|\xi|^2 t}e^{2\pi i\xi \cdot x} \mathrm{d}\xi  $$

where $\widehat{\varphi}$ is the Fourier transform of $\varphi \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (or if you prefer $\varphi \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$) i.e.
$$\widehat{\varphi}(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\varphi(x)e^{-2\pi ix\cdot\xi}\mathrm{d}x. $$

Thank you.

Comment: If $\hat{\varphi}$ is an arbitrary function of $\xi$, then you will have a convolution, no?

Comment: Yes, but I think that he wants the exact function. And the calculation to my mind is not straightforward.

Comment: I was trying to assist the OP without solving it for him. Is it not the multidimensional FT of the heat equation? I'm assuming that's a dot product of $\xi$ and $x$ in the exponential term, although I'm not very used to using the notation the OP uses.

Comment: I think it is the FT of the Schrödinger equation, because of the $i$ at the exponent.

Comment: Yeah you're right sorry, I should have looked closer at the extra $i$, it is the multidimensional version of the linear Schrodinger equation. In which case the solution is the same as the multidimensional heat equation but replacing your constant (say $a$) with $i$.

Comment: Yes, but it is more delicate to my mind, because you have to justify the change of variable. Because it's  a complex function and one has to be careful.